# how to check if it is a very first launch on a daily basis in React Native env?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, asyncstorage

Are there any ways to check if it is a very first launch on a daily basis in React Native environment?

I need to clear off the async storage of react native for users to control the popup notification system on a daily basis.

For example, if a new user launches my app for the first time in a day, it flushes the async storage and get the popup notification and save its notification key. next time in the same day, it has its notification key in the async storage so it wouldn't call the popup notification.

The next day when the user launches my app, it flushes the async storage and get the popup notification.. and over and over again with these conditions.

Would it be the built-in function in React Native? I did search but couldn't get any..

I did google and some tech blogs on the web. but nobody handled this. Can someone help me out on this case~?

Comment: You can store date in `AsyncStorage` and compare with previous day's date. If the dates are unequal you can clear async storage as you want show popup.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I did try this way days ago. thanks!!

Comment: Solution worked for you?

Comment: I solution worked please provide a upvote to the same, that would be helpful.

Thanks :)